# how to dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I read a lot of documentation about this before i decided to ask.
So I have navigationController in my app. When user enters the first time in my app I do this

```
RegViewController *opr = [[RegViewController alloc] init];
self.regController = opr;
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:self.regController animated:NO];
[opr release];
```

And it works fine. But when I click OK button in RegViewController I call this method

```
-(IBAction)btn_regPressed:(id)sender
{
   NSLog(@"start to dissmis modal");
 [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
//[self.navigationController.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
```

But this code doesn't want to dismissModalViewController
Can somebody help me with thios issue please. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your RegViewController, try to dismiss self like so:

```
-(IBAction)btn_regPressed:(id)sender
{
   NSLog(@"start to dissmis modal");
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! it works!!! i read that i have to do self.navigationController but self works! THANK YOU AGAIN

Answer (score 1):

try to change your call to (remove the navigationController):

```
[self presentModalViewController:self.regController animated:NO];
```

and in your button (remove the navigationController):

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

You are telling to your navigationController dismiss your modal, but your viewcontroller should do it.
Navigation controllers are used to navigation (go and back) purposes. And probably, your navigationController is nil.